# how to get username and password entered in vaadin flow LoginForm?

Tags: authentication, vaadin, vaadin-flow

How to get username and password entered in vaadin flow LoginForm? I know it is from e, but how?

If this is not possible how can I extend the `LoginForm` and modify the authenticate(e) method?

```
    LoginForm component = new LoginForm();
component.addLoginListener(e -> {
    boolean isAuthenticated = authenticate(e);
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        navigateToMainPage();
    } else {
        component.setError(true);
    }
});

add(component);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
e.getUsername()
```

Answer (score 0):

`e` ist a [`AbstractLogin.LoginEvent`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.6.8/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/AbstractLogin.LoginEvent.html) that has a `getUsername()` and a `getPassword()` Methode.

Answer (score 0):

That only works after the login has occurred. If you want the username before the login takes place, you're out of luck. Vaadin doesn't provide a means to get that.